# EU-issued driver's license - driving while waiting for it to be exchanged for a UK one

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, driving-license

I understand one can drive a vehicle in the UK without their **GB** driver's license, while they are waiting for their new license, after sending it to DVLA to update their address https://www.gov.uk/change-address-driving-licence.

Can one drive a vehicle in the UK without their **EU-issued** driver's licence, while they are waiting for their **GB** license, after sending their EU-issued one to DVLA to be exchanged for a GB license?

Comment: Yes. Being a correctly licensed driver is the objective. To 'hold' a licence does not mean you need to have it in your pocket. If you are stopped by police while driving, you can opt to produce your licence at a police station of your choice within 7 days.

Comment: @user16259 Do you have a link to the official document?

Comment: It doesn't fully answer the question but I thought it might cover the underlying need https://www.gov.uk/stopped-by-police-while-driving-your-rights . while the gov website for exchanging your licence says nothing on the subject of driving while waiting for your UK licence, it would be irrational to impose a restriction. I would use a tracked Postal service for this so that I have a receipt in case I was stopped by police while driving.